# How to map CapsLock to Ctrl+Alt+Super+Shift?

Tags: linux, kde

Is there a way to achieve this? It seems that using xmodmap you can only remap CapsLock to a single modifier.

I've also tried [xkeysnail](https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail) with this configuration:

```
from xkeysnail.transform import *

define_keymap(None, {K("CAPSLOCK"): [Key.LEFT_CTRL, Key.LEFT_ALT, Key.LEFT_META, Key.LEFT_SHIFT]}, "HyperShift")
```

But it doesn't seem to do what I expected.

Background: I'm on Manjaro 20.2.1 (Nibia)  using KDE Plasma. The reason for using this mapping is the fact that Qt can't comprehend they Hyper key, so I need to map CapsLock to Hyper in the MacOS style (Ctrl+Alt+Super+Shift) in order to use it in KDE shortcuts.